# Problem in uploading image to the server using XAMPP

Tags: android, mysql, xampp

I'm facing a problem while trying to upload image from the app to the server using xampp .

the thing is that when I write the image name($ImageName) manually on the PHP file it works fine but when I try with code it doesn't and show me this message ( the one on the bottom on the first click on the upload button and the other message on the second click and above ) .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxUr3.png)

this is the php file code

```
<?php
require "connection.php";
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
$DefaultId = 0;
$ImageData = $_POST['image_data'];
$ImageName =$_POST['image_tag'];  /* when I write here "stack" for example 
it works and I find the image on the path with the name stack */

$ImagePath = "Documents/$ImageName.jpg";
$ServerURL = "192.168.1.5/$ImagePath";

$InsertSQL = "INSERT INTO imageupload (image_path,image_name) values('$ServerURL','$ImageName')";

if(mysqli_query($conn, $InsertSQL)){

file_put_contents($ImagePath,base64_decode($ImageData));

echo "Your Image Has Been Uploaded.";
}
mysqli_close($conn);
}else{
echo "Please Try Again";
}

?>
```

and this is the java code (only the code in relation with the server )

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



        class AsyncTaskUploadClass extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {

                super.onPreExecute();

                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"Image is Uploading","Please Wait",false,false);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String string1) {

                super.onPostExecute(string1);

                progressDialog.dismiss();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,string1,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

                ImageProcessClass imageProcessClass = new ImageProcessClass();

                HashMap<String,String> HashMapParams = new HashMap<String,String>();

                HashMapParams.put("image_tag", GetImageNameFromEditText);

                HashMapParams.put("image_data", ConvertImage);

                String FinalData = imageProcessClass.ImageHttpRequest("http://192.168.1.5/documentupload.php", HashMapParams);

                return FinalData;
            }
        }
        AsyncTaskUploadClass AsyncTaskUploadClassOBJ = new AsyncTaskUploadClass();
        AsyncTaskUploadClassOBJ.execute();
    }

    public class ImageProcessClass{

        public String ImageHttpRequest(String requestURL,HashMap<String, String> PData) {

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            try {
                url = new URL(requestURL);

                httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(20000);

                httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(20000);

                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();

                bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(

                        new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

                bufferedWriter.write(bufferedWriterDataFN(PData));

                bufferedWriter.flush();

                bufferedWriter.close();

                outputStream.close();

                RC = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();

                if (RC == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));

                    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                    String RC2;

                    while ((RC2 = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){

                        stringBuilder.append(RC2);
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }

        private String bufferedWriterDataFN(HashMap<String, String> HashMapParams) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

            stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            for (Map.Entry<String, String> KEY : HashMapParams.entrySet()) {
                if (check)
                    check = false;
                else
                    stringBuilder.append("&amp;");

                stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(KEY.getKey(), "UTF-8"));

                stringBuilder.append("=");

                stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(KEY.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
            }

            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 5) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Now user should be able to use camera

            }
            else {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Unable to use Camera..Please Allow us to use Camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

and finally the XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:background="#E0E0E0"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Upload Image To Server"
                android:textSize="26dp"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"/>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#000"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Image Name"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageName"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Select Image"
                android:id="@+id/buttonSelect"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="270dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"/>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#000"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="right">

                <Button
                    tools:visibility="visible"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Upload >>"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:id="@+id/buttonUpload"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: There is a lot of code here. You will get better answers if you edit it down to a Minimal reproducible example as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I edited the post , there still only the asynktask code which is responsible for the operation .

Comment: can anyone help me please .

Answer (score 1):

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> KEY : HashMapParams.entrySet()) {
    if (check)
        check = false;
    else
        stringBuilder.append("&");//just give & symbol and remove amp;
    stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(KEY.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
    stringBuilder.append("=");
    stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(KEY.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
}
```

Comment: just do this simple change in the for loop while writing the data to he server stringBuilder.append("&");//just give & symbol and remove amp;